# When is the double cover of a smooth curve reducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a smooth projective plane curve. Suppose $f:C'\rightarrow C$ is a double cover of $C$ ramified at $d$ points. Suppose $C'$ is irreducible, then the Riemann Hurwitz formula says that $d$ has to be even, is that correct?

Consequently, if I know that $d$ is odd, does that mean that the double cover $C'$ is reducible?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I think you are correct. The RH-formula for a branched double cover $f:S' \rightarrow S$ gives:$$ \chi(S') = 2\chi(S) - \sum_{p \in S'}(E_{p}-1) $$ where $e(p)$ is the ramification index at $p\in S'$. Since $f$ is a ramified cover of degree 2 the map is $2:1$ on the complement of the ramification subset, implying that $e(p) \leq 2$ for all $p \in S'$, since otherwise we get a point in $S$ (over which the map is regular) whose pre-image has more than $3$ preimages: a contradiction.

Hence, $\sum_{p \in S'}(E_{p}-1)$ is equal to the number of ramification points in $S'$, and is clearly even by the formula.

The definition of ramified cover implies easily that a ramified cover of a Riemann surface has to be a (possibly disconnected) Riemann surface. So, if a curve is branch covered by some reducible curve, then the irreducible components are pairwise disjoint smooth curves. Then we can apply the above argument to each component of the domain, giving in general that the number of ramification points is always even. Although I should mention that if $S'$ has more than one component, then we have that $S'$ is just two copies of $C$, in particular it is an unramified cover.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this statement - if a curve is branch covered a reducible curve, then the irreducible components are pairwise disjoint. Why should they be disjoint?

Comment: If they intersect then at the point of intersection the curve won't be locally a Riemann surface. This is required by the definition of branched cover.

Comment: Okay I am not talking about a Riemann surface. I am talking about projective curves as coverings which would allow singularities.

Comment: A priori $C'$ could have singularities, but the definition of covering implies that $C'$ is smooth.

Comment: That is not true. In algebraic geometry, the term covering means something more general I believe. For example, look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264784/two-ways-to-look-at-a-double-cover-of-the-projective-line

Comment: Sure, I guess you could define it to be a morphism $f: C' \rightarrow C$ with degree $n$, where $n$ the degree of the field extension $k(C')$ over $f^{*}(k(C))$.  But I don't think there is a version of RH formula that applies for such morphism. I don't even know that there is a definition of ramification index at a singular point of $C'$. For example if you consider the morphism of affine curves that maps the 2 co-ordinate axes in $\mathbb{A}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ by $(x,y  ) \mapsto x$ what would be the ramification index of that?